# Coffeescript JQuery on click only working when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app that's using coffeescript.  When I refresh the page or go to it directly using the URL, the following code works.  When I click a link through to this page and try it out, it doesn't work at all.  Why could that be?

```
jQuery ->
  console.log "Ready."
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    console.log "Click."
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

After a reload, I get Ready and Click when appropriate, and it works.  After a click through from another page, I don't get anything.  I also get this deprecation warning from chrome, which I'm not sure how to fix since it's coming from within JQuery itself:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
jquery.js?body=1:5375
```

The error only shows up when the code above isn't working.  Is chrome blocking it?  I'm using `jquery-rails (3.0.4)`

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? If so, the handler on the form is getting blown away when the DOM gets refreshed. You need to wrap it in a page:restore page:load type handler.

Comment: Yes I am.  I didn't realize I was at first.  Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out it was turbolinks that was causing the problem.  Thanks davidburber for pointing that out.  Here's what I did to fix it (from [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links))

```
ready = ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()


$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: also had to add
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
to get this to work

Answer (score 4):

There's another, more **simple** solution here.

When you use turbolinks, which is default since Rails 4, also include [jquery.turbolinks gem][1]

The instructions are quite easy.

1. In your Gemfile add: **gem 'jquery-turbolinks'**
2. In your JavaScript manifest (default: app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee):

   Require **jquery.turbolinks** immediately **after jquery**.

   Require **turbolinks after** your **scripts**.

Example:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery.turbolinks
#= require jquery_ujs

# ... your other scripts here ...

#= require turbolinks
```

With the above you neither need any change in you code nor lines:

```
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: `jquery-turbolinks` is now deprecated: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks